# JasperReport how to edit generated report HTML?

Tags: jasper-reports

Is it possible to edit HTML of generated report on servlet after exporting it with JRHtmlExporter? I just want to change generated report `<body>` tag to `<body onload="window.print()">`. All  I want is that printer can be choosed by user and not programmatically.
Thanks.

Comment: If you want to edit the HTML after JR is done with it... it doesn't really seem like a JR question. How is your question different from, "How can I edit some HTML?"?

Comment: I'll try to explain. After report generation html is passed through ResourceResponse response back to jsp page and repor's html is loaded over jsp page. So what I want is to edit html before passing it. As repor exported with JRHtmlExporter I don't know how to get final html of repor. Another problem is to display generated html in new tab, but It is certainly not JR problem. Am I made me understand or better I should post code example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically you are using the JRHtmlExporter in code like this:

```
JRHtmlExporter exporter = new JRHtmlExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "build/reports/BatchExportReport.html");
// or maybe this:
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_WRITER, out);
```

In that case you just need to process the generated file, or you need to handle the generated output stream.

But maybe you just need to set JRHtmlExporterParameter.HTML_HEADER. Take a look at that. You could set that to avoid getting this default header as shown in JRHtmlExporter.java:

```
writer.write("<body text=\"#000000\" link=\"#000000\" alink=\"#000000\" vlink=\"#000000\">\n");
```